# error must include nuiapi.h rather than including nuisensor.h directly

Tags: c++, kinect

I am trying to build some code written in C++ for getting an image via Kinect and I get   the following error:

> You must include nuiapi.h rather than including nuisensor.h directly.

but  I already included windows.h and NUIAPI.h... windows.h was included before nuiapi.h in  the source file. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

here is the code in my source file .cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Kinect.h"
#include <NuiApi.h>
#include <NuiImageCamera.h>
#include <NuiSensor.h>
```

kinectcamera::~Kinectcamera()
  {

```
  SafeRelease<IMediaObject>(&pDMO);
  SafeRelease<INuiAudioBeam>(&pAudio);
```

Comment: Including nuiapi.h defines `NUIAPI`, and the error you've asked about happens because `NUIAPI` isn't defined.  It would be best to show a short example of how you are handling the includes.

Comment: @ Retired Ninja,  I have edited my file ...

Comment: Does the compiler give you some more details about the error?

Comment: nuiapi.h includes the other nui* files.  You shouldn't include them on their own which is what the error message says.